# "There were no net reputation changes on this day"

Tags: discussion, reputation

Yesterday I saw my reputation increase, and then decrease again in a few seconds. I guess someone upvoted, and then changed their mind.

After than in my reputation page a record appeared for that day:
[image]

I'm curious if this done purposely. Is this done deribately or does this record appear because somewhere in the StackExchange db a reputation change was marked for this day and wasn't reverted?

Comment: "I guess someone upvoted, and then changed their mind." The more likely explanation here is a combination of a tiny mobile screen and fat fingers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, not having access to the source code, but I suspect that changes within the 5 minute window during which votes can be changed wouldn't be recorded. So in your case the up-vote followed immediately by the removal of that vote are effectively not recorded.

If the vote had "hardened" and then you edited the post which would allow the vote to be changed, then that change would be recorded. You'd still have a net gain of 0 but you'd see two lines one for the initial upvote and a second for its removal.